# Replace items from the back of a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace a few occurrences from the end of a string. I have tried this:

```py
replace_me="<!doctype html><html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>"
print('replacing 3 matches of > from back of string. please wait...')
replace_me.replace('>','&gt;',-1)
print(replace_me)
```

But it gives me unreplaced output: `<!doctype html><html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>`

[Complete Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjQbq.png)

Is it even possible to replace the last few occurrences of a string?

Comment: A few? what is a few?

Comment: @BuddyBoblll I meant, like, let's say 3 occurrences from the back.

Comment: Oh alright, lol

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're replacing from the back, you can just flip the string and replace it with your backwards match too to replace N occurrences:

```
replace_me="<!doctype html><html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>" 
N=3 
newstr = '&gt;'[::-1]
replace_me_new = replace_me[::-1].replace('>',newstr,N)[::-1]
print(replace_me_new)
```

which outputs:

```
<!doctype html><html><body><p>hello</p&gt;</body&gt;</html&gt;
```

To generalize in a way that mimics `str.replace()`:

```py
def rreplace(s, old, new, count=-1):
    return s[::-1].replace(old[::-1], new[::-1], count)[::-1]
```

Comment: wouldn't `reversed(s)` be clearer than `s[::-1]`?

Comment: neat idea!  You could also reverse the match for a general solution: `def rreplace(s, old, new, count=-1): return s[::-1].replace(old[::-1], new[::-1], count)[::-1]`.

Comment: @PatrickParker: `reversed()` is an iterator, doesn't return a new sequence until you do something like `''.join(reversed(...))`. Also, `'reversed' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def replace_last(a, b, s, n=1):
    for _ in range(n):
        i = s.rindex(a)
        s = s[0:i] + b + s[i+len(a):]
    return s
```

Usage:

```py
>>> replace_last('>', '&gt;', "<!doctype html><html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>", n=3)
'<!doctype html><html><body><p>hello</p&gt;</body&gt;</html&gt;'
```

Comment: I like @jhso's solution better: it can let the builtin `str.replace()` deal with corner cases, such as when the pattern to match contains the replacement -- which my solution here definitely doesn't handle.